# Consecutive inline enumerate with different number and characters, how to?

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I need to create the following output

```
1. [J1] bla bla bla
2. [J2] bla bla bla
....
13. [J13] bla bla bla
14. [C1] bla bla bla
15. [C2] bla bla bla
...
21. [B1] bla bla bla
```

Is there anyone who has ideas how to get it?

Answer (score 3):

This also copes with references. You're not required to have `\item` outside `subenumerate`, they're added just by way of example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{enumz}
\newenvironment{bienumerate}
 {\enumerate\setcounter{enumz}{0}\let\item\bi@item}
 {\endenumerate}
\newenvironment{subenumerate}[1]
 {\setcounter{enumz}{0}\def\bi@prefix{#1}}
 {}
\let\ltx@item\item
\newcommand{\bi@item}{%
\@ifundefined{bi@prefix}
    {\ltx@item}
    {\stepcounter{enumz}\ltx@item\relax
     \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \@currentlabel~% <----------- comment this if you don't want the item number in the \ref
       [\bi@prefix\theenumz]%
     }%
     [\bi@prefix\theenumz]~}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test of reference: \ref{test}.

\begin{bienumerate}

\item bla bla bla

\begin{subenumerate}{J}
\item\label{test} bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\end{subenumerate}

\begin{subenumerate}{B}
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\end{subenumerate}

\item bla bla bla

\begin{subenumerate}{C}
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\end{subenumerate}
\end{bienumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you comment the marked line, the reference line will be like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newlist{inlinelist}{enumerate*}{1}


\newcommand{\inlineformat}[1]{%
  [#1]%
}

\setlist[inlinelist,1]{font={\bfseries},label*={\arabic*}}
\begin{document}

\begin{inlinelist}[label*={\inlineformat{J\arabic*}}]
\item Foo
\item Foobar
\end{inlinelist}

\begin{inlinelist}[label*={\inlineformat{C\arabic*}}]
\item Foobar
\item Foo
\item Otherstuff
\end{inlinelist}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you want to specify the syntax. The simplest way would be to define commands that differ from your regular `\item`-like list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{numchar}
\newcommand{\numchar}{}
\newcommand{\setnumchar}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\numchar}{#1}% Update \numchar
  \setcounter{numchar}{0}}% Reset numchar counter
\newcommand{\nextitem}{%
  \item \relax\stepcounter{numchar}[\numchar\thenumchar]~\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \setnumchar{J}
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla

  \setnumchar{C}
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla

  \setnumchar{B}
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
  \nextitem bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Above I've defined `\nextitem` to act like an `\item` with some added content. The added content matches your requirement, as laid out by `\setnumchar` - a macro that updates the inner enumeration *character* as well as resets the inner enumeration.

---

If you wish to maintain the `\item`-like usage, you can use the following updated definition of `\setnumchar`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{numchar}
\newif\iffirstset
\newcommand{\numchar}{}
\newcommand{\setnumchar}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\numchar}{#1}% Update \numchar
  \setcounter{numchar}{0}% Reset numchar counter
  \iffirstset\else
    \firstsettrue
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand{\item}{%
      \olditem\relax\stepcounter{numchar}[\numchar\thenumchar]~\ignorespaces}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \setnumchar{J}
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla

  \setnumchar{C}
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla

  \setnumchar{B}
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```